# Can I build a mobile app that feeds from data in already installed apps?

Tags: android, ios, permissions

I want to build an app that uses data from already installed apps - with permission from the user.

ex.
Economic Advisor app that can get the transactions from the banking app.
The receipts from the shopping categorization app (Mint, Spiiir, Spenderlog).
Your portfolio from your trading app.
etc..

Would that in any creative way be possible?

- it could be permissions on the phone (if possible)
- screenshots by user
- letting "Economic advisor" come along on a user controlled tour in all the needed apps.  User should then open apps and navigate, while "Economic  Advisor" should get screenshots of the relevant information.

Is any of this possible, or could it be done much simpler?

Best regards
Lasse

Comment: not in iOS, applications are strictly isolated from one another, unless it's the same developer.

Comment: you can get only the data which the other apps are willing to provide you with, not any data you want (in Android). For that you will need to check each app's API (if it has it).